# variable argument in sql query function

Tags: sql, go

This is my code

```
func QueryMap2(db *sql.DB, query string, args ...interface{}) (error) {
rows, err := db.Query(query, args...)
if err!=nil {
    return err
}
```

....

```
dblib.QueryMap2(myDB, "select * from user where userid=?", "admin")
```

This is error message

panic: interface conversion: interface {} is int64, not []uint8

help me

Comment: Edit the question to include the stack trace printed with the panic and the panicking line of code.